# how can I use mutate in dplyr to modify variable dynamically?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I wish to dynamically select variables and modify them in tibble dataframe. I have copied a sample problem. Can someone please help with that.
Thanks

```
df <- tibble(
x = c(1, 2, 3),
y = c(4, 5, 6),
z = c(6, 7, 8))

variables = c("x", "y")

for (var in variables)
{
   df <- df %>% mutate(var = var + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(all_of(variables), ~ . + 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     5     6
#2     3     6     7
#3     4     7     8
```

#### data

```
df <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(4, 5, 6),
  z = c(6, 7, 8))
variables = c("x", "y")
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, if we wanted to add the updates as new columns instead of overwriting the existing ones, how would you need to modify the mutate statement? Still trying to figure out how to use ```mutate``` and ```across``` in place of ```mutate_at``` for creating new columns.

Comment: Aha, figured it out '''df %>% mutate(across(all_of(variables), list(test = ~ . + 1)) )'''

Comment: @RussThomas You can use `.names = "{col}_test"` within `across`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can use `!!` from `rlang` and `sym()` from `dplyr` to make the evaluation you want using the operator `:=`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data and code
df <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(4, 5, 6),
  z = c(6, 7, 8))

variables = c("x", "y")

for (var in variables)
{
  var <- sym(var)
  df <- df %>% mutate(!!var := !!var + 1)
}
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     5     6
2     3     6     7
3     4     7     8
```